# UIView.animateWithDuration stops after scrolling uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uianimation

i have added a infinite animation in uiTableViewCell which just blinks a UILabel inside the table view cell.

my problem is, when i scrolls the tableview it just stops the blinking

my code is

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TripListCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TripListCell
    
    let trip = tripList[indexPath.section]
    cell.lblTripDirection.textColor = UIColor(red: 51/255, green: 210/255, blue: 123/255, alpha: 1.0)
    
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .Repeat, .Autoreverse, .AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
        
        cell.lblTripDirection.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: {
            bool in
        cell.lblTripDirection.alpha = 1.0
        cell.lblTripDirection.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    })
    return cell
}
```

Update:

UIView.commitAnimations() before returning the cell worked for me.
Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UIView.commitAnimations() before returning the cell worked for me.

Comment: Where did you declare the UIView.commitAnimations() ? Do you have an working example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can override `prepareForReuse` method of the UITableViewCell in your custom cell `TripListCell`.

`prepareForReuse` is called every time whenever `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is called.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` resuse the same cell to display other data. so you shouln't write your animation in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

You should try to write in `awakeFromNib` of `custom cell class` or you should use `willDisplayCell` method to write animation.

hope this will help :)

Comment: awakeFromNib: problem remains same ,

Comment: @ParthBhuva this is a very old question, but did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code in this UITableViewDelegate method :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

TableViews reuse their cells so inevitably your label stop their animation.

You can restore the reused cell to its default state either in `prepareForReuse:` on the custom table view cell or in the [`tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:).

In this case you use UIView animations, you only need to change the value of the animated property to cancel the animation and return to the default state.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //declaring the cell variable again

    var cell: TripListCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TripListCell
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        cell.lblTripDirection.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    // do your animation..
    ...
}
```